# An integral of a sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

$\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is a bounded domain with smooth boundary $\partial\Omega$. Does
$$
\liminf_{k\rightarrow\infty} \int_{\Omega} \rho(u_k)\,dx
\geq 
\int_{\Omega} \liminf_{k\rightarrow\infty} \rho(u_k)\,dx
$$
hold when $\rho$ is a $C^1$ function, and the sequence of functions $\{ u_k(x) \}_{k=1}^{k=\infty}\in H^1_{0}(\Omega)$ satisfies
\begin{equation}
 u_k \rightarrow u^{\ast} \quad \text{a.e.} \quad \text{in}\quad \Omega \quad \text{as} \quad  k\rightarrow \infty?
\end{equation}

Comment: Fatou's lemma is for non-negative functions.

Comment: You are right. Actually I'm asking whether that inequality is true or not.

Comment: Probably not even for $\rho(x)=x$: Choose the $u_k$ negative and $u^*\not\in L^1(\Omega)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making *Your Ad Here*'s example explicit: fix $x_0\in \Omega$ and let $\rho(t)= - t$. Define  $u_k(x) = k^{n-1} \max(0, 1-k|x-x_0|)$. The graph of $k$ is the  cone with vertex $(x_0,k^{n-1})$ and base $B(x_0,1/k)$. For large $k$ we have $u_k\in H^1_0(\Omega)$.

On one hand, $\int_{\Omega} \rho( u_k)$ is a fixed negative value, independent of $k$. On another hand, $u_k\to 0$ a.e.

Comment: Thank you for providing this example! I will check it.